# Unable to increase pandas dataframe decimal precision

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I make the following dataframe in python:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Blue', 34], ['Green', 61], ['Red', 22]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Color', 'Value'])

df
```

and see:

```
    Color   Value
------------------
0    Blue      34
1   Green      61
2     Red      22
```

I then want to divide the "Value" column by 7, yielding new values in each row that will not divide evenly and have many decimal places of precision.

I then divide by 7 with:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value']/7
df
```

And I see:

```
     Color   Value
-------------------
0     Blue    4.86
1    Green    8.71
2      Red    3.14
```

But I want to see more decimal precision than this. I would like to see 5 decimal places of precision.

And so I try using the `.round(5)` function with:

```
df.round(5)
```

And nothing has changed to the precision of the values, still just 2 decimal places.

I am not sure why selecting 5 decimal places here is not being applied to my indicated data frame.

I also tried increasing the precision with:

```
pd.set_option('display.precision',5)
```

before calling the dataframe, but this changed nothing.

How can I fix this code so that I get values with 5 decimal places of precision? This is pertaining to increasing decimal precision, instead of specifically rounding down.

Comment: The actual precision is higher than the **displayed** precision. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html especially the option `display.precision`.

Comment: I tried to enter `pd.set_option('display.precision', 4)` above my code, and I still see the same 2 decimal places displayed. It seems like that's all I needed to do referring to the pandas docs, but the decimal places just are not changing.

Comment: It works for me. Can you show what you tried as one continuous block of code in the question? Which version of pandas do you use (`print(pd.__version__)` tells it)?